# When are Type Objects for Value Types created?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, compilation, value-type

I know that when we define a struct with some methods in it, compiler knows what method to invoke(infers the type and calls the corresponding method from metadata, no need for boxing, correct me if I'm wrong). However, when boxing value types, a reference to its TYPE OBJECT is stored and when calling a method on a boxed value type the compiler looks for it in the TYPE OBJECT'S method table.

Is the TYPE OBJECT created when we first access the value type or the first time it is boxed?

Comment: You mean, when you copy a value type into an object reference? like: `object a = 10;`?

Comment: Yes, moving their actual value to the managed heap and accessing their value by reference.

Comment: Sometimes called "type handle", the CLR name for is "method table pointer".  Gets created very early, the just-in-time compiler needs it to get its job done.  It is an unmanaged pointer to the CLR's type description.  You can't use any type without one, boxing doesn't make it special.

Comment: Boxing causes the boxed value type to have a reference to it's type object, and at that point it must have been created. So when was it created?
Are you saying that the type object is the same as the "method table pointer" and when boxed, the object in the managed heap is storing a pointer to that table?